# Controlling windows services via the web?

Tags: windows, service, controls

I've been thinking of a piece of software and wondering if it exists ... a quick scout around on google indicates that it doesn't.

Here's our problem, we have a bunch of global services that run at various international locations. We need to globally control these services, for example a global bounce (something that occurs every weekend). This involves logging into each box remotely and restarting and then waiting for the services to start. It takes and age.

I was think that a piece of software must exist that allows you to logon via a web services and control the services from all the locations via one web site. What's more you would be able to schedule a restart (so there was no need for user intervention).

Now I could write this .... but someone must have written this already .... or it's part of some windows add-on?

Any ideas?

Cheers
Rich

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Powershell script and WMI to start/stop the services...

Comment: There's a few issues with this, first the passwords would be in clear text. Secondly I really want a plush interface that within a few seconds I can get a clear picture of the global services.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the [**sc**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599(WS.10).aspx) command? It lets you control remote services and is already built into the operating system, e.g.:

```
sc \\servername stop "servicename"
sc \\servername start "servicename"
```

Another option is Mark Russinovich's [**PSService** tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542.aspx).

Comment: Yeah this would be ok if we had 1 or 2 services. However we have about 20 services in about 8 locations over the world. We already have command line tools, I want to move away from these ways of operating and have a nice friendly interface that anyone can use.

Comment: If you're thinking about web-based interface, you'll have to solve the authorization problem. I assume that you would not want "anyone" to be able to stop/start services, but only authorized users. The problem is that you can authorize users in the web app, but the outgoing calls (from web app to service control manager on the remote servers) will be made under credentials of web process (e.g. ASPNET), which normally does not have rights to manage services (and you would not it to have these rights). Just something to think about before you get emotionally vested in the web-based approach.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I'm pretty sure can use WMI from within ASP.NET. This will allow me to authorise against LDPA, I'm also pretty sure that ASP.NET itself can authorise against LDPA.